# Root spaces for symplectic Lie algebra $\mathfrak{s} \mathfrak{p}_n$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry

Consider the symplectic Lie algebra $\mathfrak{s} \mathfrak{p}_n$ over a field $K$.

I know that the root system is given by 
$C_n=\{\pm 2e_j, \pm e_j \pm e_k:j,k=1 \cdots n, j \neq k\} $

where $e_k(diag(h,-h))=h_k$ with $h \in K$.

I do not know what are the *corresponding root spaces for* *each root*. Thank you for discussing the root spaces (possibly with the help of matrices, diagrams so that it is easier for me to understand).

Comment: This is treated carefully in, e.g., Fulton & Harris, (I think) $\S$17.

Comment: Fulton and Harris is very difficult to read for me. Also it contains more details than necessary for this question.

Comment: @MathStudent What you mean by $e_k(diag(h,-h))=h_k$? What are $h$ and $h_k$? and what is $diag(h,-h)$? Is it a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote the positive roots $a_{ij} = e_i - e_j$ (for $i<j$), $b_i = 2e_i$, $c_{ij} = e_i + e_j$ (for $i<j$). Then the root subspaces correspond to the matrix enries in the following way:

$\begin{equation} \left(\begin{array}{lllll|lllll}
\ast & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} & b_1 & c_{12} & c_{13} & \cdots & c_{1n} \\
-a_{12} & \ast & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2n} & c_{12} & b_2 & c_{23} & \cdots & c_{2n} \\
-a_{13} & -a_{23} & \ast & \cdots & a_{3n} & c_{13} & c_{23} & b_3 & \cdots & c_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-a_{1n} & -a_{2n} & -a_{3n} & \cdots & \ast & c_{1n} & c_{2n} & c_{3n} & \cdots & b_n \\ \hline
%
-b_1 & -c_{12} & -c_{13} & \cdots & -c_{1n} & \ast & -a_{12} & -a_{13} & \cdots & -a_{1n} \\
-c_{12} & -b_2 & -c_{23} & \cdots & -c_{2n} & a_{12} & \ast & -a_{23} & \cdots & -a_{2n} \\
-c_{13} & -c_{23} & -b_3 & \cdots & -c_{3n} & a_{13} & a_{23} & \ast & \cdots & -a_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-c_{1n} & -c_{2n} & -c_{3n} & \cdots & -b_n & a_{1n} & a_{2n} & a_{3n} & \cdots & \ast
\end{array} \right) \end{equation}.$

Recall that a matrix from $\mathfrak{sp}$ must have its upper-right and lower-left block symmetric, and that lower-right block is negative transpose of upper left. So root subspaces are one dimensional.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by saying ' the root subspaces correspond to the matrix entries in the following way'. For example what is $\mathfrak{g}_{b_i}$ or what is  $\mathfrak{g}_{-b_i}$?

Comment: So $\mathfrak{g}_{b_i}$ is one dimensional span of the matrix $E_{i,n+i}$ (which has $1$ on the coordinates $(i,n+i)$, and $0$'s elswhere). That is why $b_i$ is written on the position $(i,n+i)$ in the above answer. In the same way $\mathfrak{g}_{-b_i}$ is span of $E_{n+i,i}$.

Comment: The lower right block  in the matrix not the negative transpose of the left upper block. Is the lower right block of the matrix is written correctly?

Comment: If you take a matrix from $\mathfrak{sp}$, then its lower right block is the negative transpose of the left upper block. That does not apply to root subspaces (big matrix in my answer), because taking negatives does not land you in the opposite root subspace, but stays in the same subspace. I will edit it in my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: So, $\mathfrak{g}_{a_{12}}=K (E_{1,2}+E_{n+2,n+1})$ is true? or it should be $\mathfrak{g}_{a_{12}}=K (E_{1,2}-E_{n+2,n+1})$

Comment: The letter one. You can check by definition of root subspace. The first one $E_{1,2}+E_{n+2,n+1}$ is not in $\mathfrak{sp}$.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Im a bit confused as to why the upper right block (and similarly the lower left block) has b_1 along the main diagonal and not the anti diagonal. For example if one computes the root space decomposition of $\mathfrak{sp}_2(\mathbb{C})$ with respect to the diagonal Cartan sub algebra, one sees that the root sending $e_{11}-e_{44}$ to $0$ and $e_{22}-e_{33}$  to $2$ has root space $\left<e_{23}\right>$ and similarly the one sending $e_{11}-e_{44}$ to $2$ and $e_{22}-e_{33}$ to $0$ has root space $\left<e_{14}\right>$. Where am I going wrong?